# Ubuntu Hide Desktop Icon Problem Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, icons, nemo

I am facing the scenario as below whenever I try to hide the Desktop Icon for Ubuntu 13.10.

1. When my default File Manager is set to Nautilus, everything is working fine even after I set the Desktop Icon to "Hide" from Ubuntu Tweak tool.
2. Problem is when I set my default File Manager (`xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search`) to either Nemo or Caja, whenever the file manager start, the Desktop will be shown with icon and I will need to manually kill the file manager process for the Desktop Icon to be hidden again.

Any advice on what is the cause of this?

Regards and thank you,
Roger.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command in a Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T):

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
```

This will disable the desktop-items when starting nemo.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Run these commands in terminal

```
gsettings set  org.nemo.desktop home-icon-visible false
gsettings set  org.nemo.desktop trash-icon-visible false
gsettings set  org.nemo.desktop computer-icon-visible false
gsettings set  org.nemo.desktop volumes-visible false
```